# Customer asking for a sign out that does not really sign out to obscure that the user is not signed out

Tags: authentication

I have a customer running my application with SAML SSO. This solution supports SLO (single logout). Due to their environment, a logout does not always sign the user out of the SAML IdP. This results in clicking "Sign Out" in my application effectively appearing to be a no-op:

1. LogoutRequest SP->IdP
2. LooutResponse IdP->SP
3. Redirect to `/`
4. AuthnRequest SP->IdP
5. User is already logged in (Kerberos) and is not prompted for login
6. Assertion IdP->SP
7. User is back at my application, fully logged in a few seconds after clicking logout

The customer is asking to have users redirected to the company web site after the SAML LogoutResponse is received. I have serious issues doing this as it seems to deceive the user into thinking they are logging out when they are not.

Assuming I am correct and this would be a serious issue, does anyone have any other alternative ideas? Are there any articles/documents regarding this type of thing I could show my customer to dissuade him?

Comment: Would your customer allow a popup notification that the user has not been logged out (with instructions on how to do so)? 

EDIT:  While still redirecting as the customer requests.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? A possible implementation for logging out your users until a new login? Or is this a question on how to handle a customer that has an - in your eyes - unethical request? Or do you want to know the security implications of leaving your users logged in although they think that they are logged out? The first two of these questions are unfortunately off-topic here, the third can be on-topic, but it should be reflected in you question.

Comment: @DarkMatter The difficulty is that my application does not know if the user was actually signed out of not (under some circumstances they are, under others they are not). If it did, it could act accordingly. The current flow, while potentially irritating to users, seems to be ideal. If they are not signed out, it should be clear to them.

Comment: @TomK.Assuming I am correct about this being a security issue, what kind of documentation can I provide my customer to dissuade him?

Comment: You can have a look here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_logout_functionality_(OTG-SESS-006)

Comment: It sounds like the issue isn't that they aren't logging out, but that due to a combination of your app attempting login from / and the IdP doing Kerberos integrated login that they are immediately logging back in.  If so, going to a logout notice park page would work (they'd still be logged out); or changing so you don't attempt IdP login without user interaction (a login button/page).
Either way, the issue isn't that they aren't logging out, the issue is that once they log out they are then immediately logging back in (common on IdPs that use, for example, integrated windows auth)

Comment: @Ruscal: is basically what my workplace does, which is somewhat annoying, but sensible. It has a message about closing your browser tab and how you're possibly still signed into the SSO. I wish it had a link back to the app you signed out from...

Comment: @Ruscal I disagree somewhat. The issue is that auth to the IdP could be either Kerberos or username/password. When signed in via Kerberos, the user should not have the option for SLO, as the user will still be effectively logged in to all SPs that leverage that IdP. On the other hand, when signed in via username/password, SLO must be enabled in order for it to be possible to sign out. Unfortunately, I fear my customer may not go for a "You may or may not be logged out" message as part of the SLO flow.

Comment: @Ben That is a choice from the IdP, not you. From your (the app designer) side, you have to consider that it's possible that **every** IdP is using integrated authentication (since you can't control), and then build your application accordingly. Just remember the rule of RFC-s, if it *may* happen, then it *will* happen (unless explicitly not allowed, someone will always do it and justify it with "the standard says I can") I know that it can feel off to park it at a "you've been logged out page" (every MS site), but unless you request the IdP login again, they are logged out. Hence button idea.